# Info needed on PSLV launch adaptors and configurations

Tags: launch, payload, isro, payload-deployment, pslv

I want to understand how satellites are accommodated in PSLV. I know about few configurations and adaptors that've been used in the past. Is there any document which gives detailed info on Multiple Satellite Adaptor Version 2 (MSA-V2), Multiple Satellite Adaptor Version 8 (MSA-V8) and other adaptors that are there? I've noticed that there are support structures on Equipment Bay. I need info on them. What variations are there when it comes to Dual Launch Adaptors. I want to learn about those as well.

https://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1999ESASP.430..547R/0000553.000.html

On page no 553, four Payload Envelope Configurations are shown. I want to learn more about those. Specifically about the two middle configurations.

If there's anyone who knows about this or knows someone who knows about this, please answer.

Comment: Apart from MSA-V2 and V8, apparently there is MSA-V5 as well. Here is a tender for it, https://web.archive.org/web/20180917170635/https://vssc.eprocure.isro.gov.in/tnduploads/vssc/tndheader/IDT01156800000000000isro05401.pdf   Vertical dispenser has not been used till date, as far as I am aware. Unfortunately detailed documents on these are not public and all we have are visual references from campaign images, like this flat deck config from PSLVC-34 etc. https://twitter.com/COMDEV_Intl/status/742349375045787648/photo/1

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. Do you think the ISRO would reveal non-confidential info on this if I reach out to them?

Comment: They should, do try to contact them. Ideally this all should be public in a form of user manual or as brochure.

Comment: Yeah, Exactly! I'll get in touch with them soon.